# How to know the url path from a view function of another url in django?

Tags: django, url

I have a set of URLs:

```
/home/
/register/
/login/
/puzzle/<pk>
```

All of the first 3 urls can make a request to the last url.

Is it possible to know which urls are calling the `/puzzle/<pk>`, from the view function attached to it?

**Edit**

So the problem is it's a puzzle game and every user has a level. If he completes a certain level only then he can proceed to the next level. Therefore, if a user has completed **level 3**, I'll always show him the html page with the url `/puzzle/4`.

The flow is :

A user registers. His level is 0. As soon as he registers he'll be redirected to `puzzle/1/`

A user logs in. If he has completed level **x**, as soon as he logs in he'll be redirected to `/puzzle/x+1`.

I've handled these 2 types.

But the problem is, say the user is in the page `/puzzle/1/`. Now if he manually changes the url to `/puzzle/2/`, from the view function attached to `/puzzle/<pk>/`, how can I handle the above case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you want to know referring page/url, you can get it from [META attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META): `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: What do you mean, they "make a request"? How? Show some code.

Comment: @Borut `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` gave an error. I tried  `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` but it gave me `Null`. 
I've edited my question.  Can you please a take a look

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [`request.resolver_match`.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match) You could access the view name with [`request.resolver_match.view_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch)

Edit:

If I understand your model correctly, you need some logic like the following. You'll need to adjust the view name and params in `reverse`.

```
def view(request, puzzle_level):
    if puzzle_level != request.user.level_completed + 1:
        return redirect(
            reverse(
                'puzzle_view_name',
                kwargs={'puzzle_level': request.user.level_completed + 1},
            )
        )
     ...
```

Comment: I've edited my question. Can you kindly give an example with your answer with the scenario I've mentioned?

Comment: How do you validate how many puzzles they've solved? If you can get that count, you can make sure the url path is correct.

Comment: I've a param named `level_completed` for each user. It stores how many puzzle he has solved. But the main problem is, I'm already in the page with the url `/puzzle/2/` and from this page a user can change the url to `/puzzle/3/` manually. How do I cechk this from the view function?

Comment: one more thing, is it possible to know which url is calling a url? I meant, from `/puzzle/5/` a request can be made to the url `puzzle/6/`. So is it possible to know that `/puzzle/5/` is requesting url `/puzzle/6/` with Django?

Comment: That's the referer that Borut was mentioning.

Comment: It's actually returning me Null